# Function Call as parameter of another function on Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing

First of all, i need this to be capabe to run on I.E. 8 at least (work requirements) and i can't use jQuery or another library to reach this.

The "issue" is that there's a function onKeyDown with a preventDefault and a function triggered onChange, which never (or randomly) executes due to prevendefault (long to explain more). I't could be solved as i'm reading onChange value and i'm setting it as onPlay, then i delete onchange attribute and the behaviour is to check if changes exists when onBlur and i'm triggering onplay event from this control function if there are changes.

Well, onPlay event (and other multimedia events) are only supported on IE 9 and up, so i need to find a way to pass through this. i can't use other events as they could be used on somewhere and could cause issues.

My idea was to send onChange value as function parameter to control function and execute it instead on triggering onplay event, but is causing me headache, it simply does nothing when i'm trying to do it.

```
 //this is a resume of the function:   
function foo(obj){
                    var funcioChange = toString(obj.getAttribute('onChange'));
                    obj.setAttribute('onBlur', 'checkChanges("'+obj.getAttribute("id")+', '+ funcioChange+'")');
                    obj.removeAttribute('onChange', 0);
            }
```

When onBlur:

```
function checkChanges(idinput, functOnChange){
    if (foo){
         functOnChange;
//another things
     }
 }
```

Comment: Just put parenthesis after the parameter name when you want to execute it... `if (foo) functOnChange();`  The parameter is a reference to the function, so you can execute it in the exact same way you normally would through code.

Comment: Even if this function has parameters?  
f.e. foo(document.getElementById('id').value)

Comment: Depending on what the parameters are, you may need to pass them into the calling function, but yes - just call it by the variable name, as if that's what the function is called, with any required parameters.

Comment: LOL, it was an error on the other part of function that made my colleague, nevermind, it works calling it without () (as if i put () it throws "is not a function" error). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Check my comment below - you're not doing what you think you're doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the function doesn't have parameter/s or you need to put it/them later in another function, you can do

```
foo = yourFunction;
function2 (foo){
 foo(param1, param2);
}
```

if you have to send the params with the function call:

```
foo = "yourFunction(param1, param2)";
function2 (foo){
 foo;
}
```

Comment: That's not correct.  In the 2nd example `foo` is being set to the result of `yourFunction(param1, param2)`.  You're not executing that inside `function2` at all

Comment: it's working to me actually on all browsers and it runs nice. Which is the supposed issue with that?

Comment: Why have you edited it to make it worse>  It was not working - you just thought it was.